# Implement POST with Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have this html form which is working fine when I open it in web browser:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no cache" />
      <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no cache" />
      <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="0" />
   </head>
   <body OnLoad="AutoSubmitForm();">
      <form name="downloadForm" action="https://c3-test.wirecard.com/acssim/app/bank" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value="eJxtU9tuozAQ......." />
         <input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value="https://www.test.com" />
         <input type="hidden" name="MD" value="optionalValue" />
         <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
             function AutoSubmitForm() { document.downloadForm.submit();} 
         </SCRIPT>
         <input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

I tried this code:

```
WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder();
            WebClient cliensst = builder.build();
            String w = cliensst.post().uri(url)
                            .header("PaReq", pareq)
                            .header("TermUrl", "https://www.test.com")
                            .header("MD", "")
                            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                            .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

But I get error: `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request`

What is the proper way to implement this?

Comment: by sending formdata using formData and not send formdata as headers.... https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-body-form

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one.

```
public static <T> T executeApiForFormData(String url, Map<String, String> payload, Map<String, String> headers, Class<T> clazz) {
        WebClient client;
        WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(url);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new HttpHeaders();
        formData.setAll(payload);

        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(headers)) {
            MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new HttpHeaders();
            map.setAll(headers);
            builder.defaultHeaders((existingHeaders) -> existingHeaders.addAll(map));
        }


        client = builder.build();

        return client
                .method(HttpMethod.POST)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(clazz)
                .block();
    }
```